# Why does AWS Beanstalk AL2 Procfile for Passenger use puma socket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, passenger, procfile, amazon-linux-2

I am migrating my ruby on rails application from AWS Beanstalk Amazon Linux 1 to their new Ruby Amazon Linux 2 (AL2).

My application server is Passenger. In their [instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-platform-procfile.html), the guide says to do these 2 things:

In `Gemfile`

`gem 'passenger'`

In `Procfile`:

`web: bundle exec passenger start /var/app/current --socket /var/run/puma/my_app.sock`

What is `--socket /var/run/puma/my_app.sock` for? Is that a typo or is that needed? Aren't we using passenger and not puma?

I use a Rails 6 skeleton application (no webpacker, sprockets) and was able to load a simple page.

Bonus question, the passenger [instruction](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/advanced_guides/developing_with_passenger/ruby/rails_integration.html#rails-server-integration) says to do this in the `Gemfile`: `gem "passenger", ">= 5.3.2", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"`.

Will it still work with Beanstalk even with the additional require?